# Create flexible ggplot2 theme that 1) makes the legend and titles larger, 2) will look good irrespective of the final dimensions

Tags: r, ggplot2, stata

I currently am one of the few R users in my company, which consists predominantly of stata users. One problem I've had with making plots using ggplot2 is that the default (theme_grey()) settings have much smaller axis font and a smaller legend than what is found in stata. Moreover, in presentations I find people have trouble reading the legend and titles from a distance.

I'm aware that ggplot2 has a theming system that allows for relative sizing. What I'd ideally like to do is to create a new default theme that I'd apply to all my plots that would make legends and axis titles larger. Importantly, however, very often the graphs I make have varying dimensions when output to pdf (e.g. 8 inch x 10 inch) or ( 10 inch x 13 inch). Since I'd like to apply this theme globally, I need it to produce good/easy to read output irrespective of the dimensions I specify when outputting to pdf.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions for how to do this/how to approach the problem using ggplot2's theming system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theme system can easily scale all the (themed) text, but not in a device sized aware way. The various theme sets, including `theme_bw()`, have an argument `base_size` which is the baseline size, in points, of fonts to use for the text. Some text is rendered at that size, and some is rendered at sizes relative to that (for example, axis labels and legend labels are rendered at 80% of the baseline size). So by specifying the `base_size` argument, you can scale all that text.

However, the `base_size` is in absolute points, not in a size which is relative to the device size. So the larger the device size, the smaller the text is relative to that.